# MySQL ответ в виде JSON

Tags: mysql, json

Доброго вечера!
Может кто подскажет, если способ получить в ответ, вместо строки её JSON, т.е. не строку 1, 2, null, а {"column1"="1", "column2"="2", column3=null}?

P.S. Кроме самого банального, вручную это все прописать?

Comment: Ну, кроме того факта, что в JSON ключи и значения разделяются двоеточием, а не равенством... Получить ответ **куда**?

Comment: @D-side , имеется ввиду, например моя программа посылает запрос, и в ответ получает таблицу с одним столбцом, где значение ячейки является JSON того объекта, который представляет сущность таблицы.

Comment: На версии 5.7.8 или свежее - лехко, они знают о существовании JSON. Для младших - используй вульгарный CONCAT().

Comment: @Akina , а как?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html или https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat